# Visual Basic Dim As equivalent in C# using an Interface when there is no available constructor

Tags: c#, vb.net, constructor

Folks:
Sorry this is such a long-winded question. TL;DR: How can I do the following Visual Basic code in C# if ISomeAPIInterface has no default constructor:

```
   Visual Basic:      Dim foo As ISomeAPIInterface
```

This started out as what I thought would be a simple exercise. Interactive Brokers has an ActiveX API that can be used with Visual Basic, C# and C++/CLI to work with market data and submit orders. In general there is a set of request methods, a set of callback methods (for asynchronous messaging) and a set of interfaces that correspond to different message parameters and other objects required to request data and place orders. 
For example to place an order there is interface IOrder with constructor .createOrder().
I've written up dozens of examples of these using VB and C# but am stuck on this one example. 
For combo orders, there is one interface that does not have a constructor method.

IB ActiveX API has the following interfaces that deal with Combo orders:

```
IComboOrderLegList   with constructor .createComboLegList()
IOrder with constructor .createOrder()
IContract with constructor .createContract()
IComboLeg with no constructor
```

In Visual Basic (Assuming AxTws1 is an ActiveX control implementing the IB API) this is not a problem as we can use Dim x As Interface as in the example below:

```
    ' Create a list of Combo Legs
    Dim cllComboOrderLegs = AxTws1.createComboLegList()

    ' Create Leg 1 of the order - this works fine in Visual Basic
    Dim clLeg1 As TWSLib.IComboLeg

    ' Create Leg 2 of the order - this works fine in Visual Basic
    Dim clLeg2 As TWSLib.IComboLeg

    ' Create the master order
    Dim ordMasterOrder = AxTws1.createOrder()

    ' Create the master contract that will hold the legs
    Dim cMasterContract = AxTws1.createContract()

    ' Fill in the Combo Leg information for Leg 1
    clLeg1 = cllComboOrderLegs.Add()
    clLeg1.conId = 13457689
    clLeg1.ratio = 1
    clLeg1.action = "BUY"
    clLeg1.exchange = "SMART"

    ' Fill in the Combo Leg information for Leg 2
    clLeg2 = cllComboOrderLegs.Add()
    clLeg2.conId = 13457779
    clLeg2.ratio = 1
    clLeg2.action = "BUY"
    clLeg2.exchange = "SMART"

    ' Fill in the master contract
    cMasterContract.symbol = "MSFT"
    cMasterContract.secType = "BAG"
    cMasterContract.exchange = "SMART"
    cMasterContract.currency = "USD"
    cMasterContract.comboLegs = cllComboOrderLegs

    ' Fill in the Master Order
    ordMasterOrder.action = "BUY"
    ordMasterOrder.totalQuantity = 1
    ordMasterOrder.orderType = "MKT"

    '  Place the order (OrderID, Contract, Order)
    AxTws1.placeOrderEx(1234, cMasterContract, ordMasterOrder)
```

However in C# We try and do the same things using the same ActiveX Control:

```
   // Create a list of Combo Legs
   TWSLib.IComboLegList cllComboOrderLegs = axTws1.createComboLegList();

   // Create Leg 1 of the order
  TWSLib.IComboLeg clLeg1 = new ???????? There is no .createComboLeg constructor

   // Create Leg 2 of the order
  TWSLib.IComboLeg clLeg2 = new ????????

   // Create the master order
   TWSLib.IOrder ordMasterOrder = axTws1.createOrder();

   // Create the master contract that will hold the legs
   TWSLib.IContract cMasterContract = axTws1.createContract();

   // Fill in the Combo Leg information for Leg 1
   clLeg1 = cllComboOrderLegs.Add();
   clLeg1.conId = 3345552; // contractID
   clLeg1.ratio = 1;
   clLeg1.action = "BUY";
   clLeg1.exchange = "SMART";

   // Fill in the Combo Leg information for Leg 2
   clLeg2 = cllComboOrderLegs.Add();
   clLeg2.conId = 3345121; // contractID
   clLeg2.ratio = 1;
   clLeg2.action = "BUY";
   clLeg2.exchange = "SMART";


   // Fill in the master contract
   cMasterContract.symbol = "MSFT";
   cMasterContract.secType = "BAG";
   cMasterContract.exchange = "SMART";
   cMasterContract.currency = "USD";
   cMasterContract.comboLegs = cllComboOrderLegs;

   // Fill in the Master Order
   ordMasterOrder.action = "BUY";
   ordMasterOrder.totalQuantity = 1;
   ordMasterOrder.orderType = "MKT";

   // Place the order (OrderID, Contract, Order)
   axTws1.placeOrderEx(2345, cMasterContract, ordMasterOrder);
```

I have tried creating my own wrapper class around the IComboOrder but
whenever I try to work with it, C# complains of a mismatch between my
class and IComboOrder.

Maybe I am missing something really basic here but VB seems to be able to
do something automatically that I do not know how to do in C#. In other words
if I do this in VB:
        ' Dim clLeg1 As TWSLib.IComboLeg

What is the equivalent in C#?

If it helps, I've added two projects to GitHub. Visual Basic flavor (working):
https://github.com/rholowczak/IB_Multileg_Orders_Winforms_VisualBasic

C# Flavor (not working):
https://github.com/rholowczak/IB_Multileg_Orders_Winforms_CSharp

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think you *need* a constructor? VB never called one either.

```
TWSLib.IComboLeg clLeg1;
```

That's the equivalent to the VB line:

```
Dim clLeg1 As TWSLib.IComboLeg
```

It's this line, that actually creates a real object in both languages (plus or minus the semicolon):

```
clLeg1 = cllComboOrderLegs.Add();
```

Comment: Ah, so simple. What was messing me up was the error on  the line:  clLeg1 = cllComboOrderLegs.Add();   "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'TWSLib.IComboLeg'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"    I added the (TWSLib.IComboLeg) as a cast and it seems (so far) to be working. Thanks!